# im triying to comunicate with telnetlib to my yeelight desk lamp

Tags: python, telnetlib

im triying to comunicate with telnetlib to my yeelight desk lamp with commands like this:{"id":1,"method":"set_power","params":["on","smooth",500]} and im getting errors like this:

```
tn.write("{"id":1,"method":"set_power","params":["off","smooth",500]}")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**and my code is:**

```
import time
import telnetlib
HOST ="192.168.1.100"
tn=telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,55443)
tn.write("{"id":1,"method":"set_power","params":["off","smooth",500]}")
l=tn.read_all()
```

Comment: Your string has double quotes in side it,  so it can't be enclosed by those same quotes.   Either escape the quotes in your string ( `"\"..."` ), use another mechanism to enquote, like single quotes `'`, or model the data with json dict / list and marshal to json with `json.dumps()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
tn.write("""{"id":1,"method":"set_power","params":["off","smooth",500]}""")
```

Another way would be this :

```
import json 
tn.write(json.dumps({'id': 1, 'method': 'set_power', 'params': ['off', 'smooth', 500])}))
```

Or this :

```
tn.write('{"id":1,"method":"set_power","params":["off","smooth",500]}')
```

The point is, you have to send a json string, and be careful not to cut it using `"`

Comment: with the first i have this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "off.py", line 7, in <module>
    tn.write("""{"id":1,"method":"set_power","params":["off","smooth",500]}""")
  File "C:\Users\Μιχαλης Ξενακης\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\telnetlib.py", line 287, in write
    if IAC in buffer:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes

Comment: Use the json dumps method.  Writing json strings by hand is a fool's errand,  especially because you'll want to manipulate the data in python most likely.

Comment: with the json method i have 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes error

Comment: I think you need to send bytes instead of a common string.
Try :
```tn.write(json.dumps({'id': 1, 'method': 'set_power', 'params': ['off', 'smooth', 500])}).encode("utf8"))```